# The official quickstart for vercel/postgres with Next.js is not working?

Tags: sql, postgresql, next.js, vercel, next.js13

I am following the [quickstart guide](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres/quickstart) from the official Vercel website, however, it prompts me this error although I followed every single step correctly:
[image]

Code directly copied from the demo:

```
import { db } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
 
export default async function handler(
  request: NextApiRequest,
  response: NextApiResponse,
) {
  const client = await db.connect();
 
  try {
    await client.sql`CREATE TABLE Pets ( Name varchar(255), Owner varchar(255) );`;
    const names = ['Fiona', 'Lucy'];
    await client.sql`INSERT INTO Pets (Name, Owner) VALUES (${names[0]}, ${names[1]});`;
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(500).json({ error });
  }
 
  const pets = await client.sql`SELECT * FROM Pets;`;
  return response.status(200).json({ pets });
}
```

Maybe it's because of the fact that vercel/postgres is still in beta mode? Or I just made a stupid mistake, please help guys!

Comment: Looks at though you're missing database connection string. Do you have a .env file, and does it have POSTGRES_URL variable?

Comment: Oops ur right that was kinda silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just forgot to add a connection string, it works after that